# MethodInfo has a reference to its object owner?

Tags: c#, reflection

I get a method via reflection and I want to use the `.Invoke()` method of that `MethodInfo`. The first parameter of the Invoke is the object which that method belongs to. I was wondering if the MethodInfo object has a reference of that object somewhere. I coulnd't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MethodInfo` relates to the type, not an object of that type.  You can use that same `MethodInfo` to invoke that method on multiple objects of the same type so no, it does not have a reference to an object.  You have to pass the object on which you want to invoke the method as an argument.